# Chrome Extension Service Worker inactive after "Clear site data"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a very simple background script in my manifest v3 extension that basically waits for messages and then retrieves a value from sync storage like so:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("value", ({ value }) => {
    ... do some stuff
  }
}
```

Now this works fine until i goto the DevTools of my extension -> Application -> Storage -> Clear site data.

After that my service worker is always "inactive" and does not become active when I send messages to it. Only when I go to chrome://extensions and disable/enable the extension the service worker starts functioning again.

The weirdest thing is that my popup.js can actually still get the value from sync storage. How is that possible after I clear the site data?

Comment: You've unregistered the service worker, which is on by default. Untick it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. you are right that unticking it solves the problem. is there a way for my extension to recover from this? i have users that complain if they empty their browser history / cache that my extension does not work anymore

Comment: reinstall the extension or run 

navigator.serviceWorker.register(chrome.runtime.getManifest().background.service_worker, {scope: '/', type: chrome.runtime.getManifest().background.type})

Comment: sorry i dont understand this. should i run this code in my background script? My problem is that once users unregister service workers (for example using plugins that clean data on browser close) my extension's service worker is removed and I have no way of bringing it back when the user reopens their browser.

Comment: You can do it in the popup or another page of your extension. Also suggest your users not to clean extensions or stop using these cleaners.